# What does DSPW mean in AS400 WRKACTJOB?

Tags: ibm-midrange

When running `wrkactjob` on AS400, there's a Status field with different statuses.

`RUN` - Job is running

`TIMW` - Waiting?

`DSPW` - ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a generally useful tip for working on the IBM i.  Move your cursor to the field you are interested in knowing about and press F1 to get a help screen.  Here's the cut and pasted text from that window:

DSPW
    The initial thread of the job is waiting for input
    from a work station display.

Comment: That helps out a lot in the future. Thank you!